# Data alignment and ordering in recursively defined array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I have a question concerning the ordering and alignment of data in recursively defined arrays. Consider the following code

```
template<int rank, int dim, class T> struct recursive_array;

template<int dim,class Tp>
struct recursive_array <0,dim,Tp> {

    using value_type = Tp;

    recursive_array<0,dim,Tp>& operator=(Tp const& val)
    {
        value = val;
        return *this;
    }
    operator Tp &() {return value;}

    value_type value;
};


template<int rank, int dim, class Tp>
struct recursive_array {

    using value_type = recursive_array<rank-1, dim, Tp>;

    recursive_array<0,dim,Tp>& operator=(Tp const& val)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
            values[i] = val;

        return *this;
    }

    value_type& operator[] (unsigned int const i)
    {
        return values[i];
    }

    value_type values[dim];
};
```

The only member of `recursive_array` is a plain old c-array of `recursive_array`s of `rank-1`. At the end of the recursion, i.e. `rank == 0`, the only member `value` contains the actual data. This technique is used in the finite element library [deal.II](https://www.dealii.org/8.5.0/doxygen/deal.II/tensor_8h_source.html) to describe a class of generic Tensors, just in case you're wondering why I'm not using an ordinary c-style array.

Now let's define an array of integers 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 using the `recursive_array` class and a plain old c-style array and compare their data layout in the memory

```
//main.cc
#include<iostream>

int main () {

recursive_array<4,2,int> arr;
int carr[2][2][2][2];

for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        for(int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
            for(int l = 0; l < 2; ++l){

            int idx = i*8 + j*4 + k*2 + l;

            arr[i][j][k][l] = idx;
            carr[i][j][k][l] = idx;

            std::cout << ((int*)&(arr[0][0][0][0]))[idx]  << "   "
                      << ((int*)&(carr[0][0][0][0]))[idx] << std::endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

which creates the following output

```
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10   10
11   11
12   12
13   13
14   14
15   15
```

The data appears to be stored continuously when using `recursive_array` as it is the case for c-style arrays. This is in accordance with the [deal.II documentation](http://www.dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/classArrayView.html#a9da1e5c388b0fbccc39da522d89362ba), but it also says that

> the order in which the entries are presented [...] is undefined.

Or am I missing something?

However, independent of what this documentation says, I am interested in understanding how the above code works in general.

1. Why exactly is the data of the above code stored in a continuous chunk of memory?
2. Is this guaranteed?
3. When the data is continuously stored, what's the ordering of the elements?

Thank you very much in advance!

I compiled the above code using gcc 6.3 with `-std=c++11 -O0` and `-std=c++11 -O3` flags, both times I got the same result.

Comment: Maybe it just means they reserve the right to change the nesting order or something? It's not obvious that the "order in which the entries are presented" is related to the language or implementation, it might just be a library term.

Comment: @Useless That could be possible, but I am also not sure about that. From my perspective it sounds weird that alignment seems to be guaranteed, but the ordering is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am one of the principal deal.II developers; I did not write that particular constructor for `ArrayView` but I think I can still answer your question.

For the record: the `deal.II` mailing list is pretty active and is a good place to go for questions like this.

### Brief version

That comment is sandbagging and simply states that we might modify the layout of `Tensor` at some point in the future: hence relying on the order things have when flattened out is explicitly discouraged.

### Longer version

We rewrote the entire `Tensor` class a few years ago (fall 2015) to be defined essentially in the same way as your example; the public interface with `operator[]` and friends was reimplemented to preserve compatibility, but the underlying storage order changed IIRC (we went from hard-coding some of the lower ranks to doing everything recursively). If we change the implementation again for some reason then the in-memory order will be different; hence the comment. I believe the point that the author of that comment was trying to make was 'we might change how things are implemented in the future, so do not rely on the order of things at the moment'.

Comment: I went ahead and rewrote that comment to be less ambiguous; thanks for pointing this out! See https://github.com/dealii/dealii/pull/6147

Comment: Thank you David, but can you also explain why the data is aligned? Is this always the case for recursive arrays? I want to understand how c/c++ works in this particular case. If you could add this, I'll accept your answer.